# Ball mount ground clearance

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee, towing

I would like to install a ball mount on my 2015 Jeep Grand Cherokee but I'm not sure how high the bottom of the ball should be from ground.

I've seen different drop and rise numbers on the ball mount so i was wondering if there was some kind average or standard that would be recommended?

Comment: Isn't the drop based on the trailer ride height?

Comment: right, and i don't have any trailers to tow right now.  I was just wondering if there is some kind of standard or common height that would be good.  For example if i wanted to tow something like this `https://www.uhaul.com/Trailers/5x8-Cargo-Trailer-Rental/AV/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The height from the ground to the bottom of the ball will be determined by the trailer you're pulling, not the car.

The height of the trailer is such that the trailers hitch is horizontal with the ground, while the hitch receiver on all vehicles is attached to two points on the frame of the car, so the receiver height is fixed for the car - e.g my Subaru Forester has a lower hitch receiver height than a friends F150 by about 6 inches.

The difference in height is accommodated by the ball mount, which positions the ball such that you're pulling in a straight line horizontally through the trailer; you don't want a large upwards or downwards angle, as it will make reversing a lot harder. You can commonly get a drop of between 3/4" and 8" (and they are usually reversible, to get a rise); there are calculators on the internet if you want to work it out by math.

Unless you're doing a lot of towing of disparate trailers, you'll find that one ball mount and a couple of balls will be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, I was more wondering about what total trailer height should I be going with that would be ok with most class 3 trailers. I guess they are all different depending on what you are towing so that's kind of tricky.  I am thinking about going about 22 inches in height with my ball mount.

Comment: It's a bit like saying "which cake should I eat", when there isn't actually a cake in front of you. 

Once you have the trailer, you can measure the ideal height that would keep the trailer horizontal, and buy the correct size of drop/rise.

...and the answer to the Cake question would always be "chocolate", of course... :)